# Error: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, mobile-application

I have android application project which is old and now I want to target compileSdkVersion 33 from 30. I have made change and also I have added android:exported in activity in AndroidManifest file but still I am getting this error when try to run. Application builds without error but whenever I try to run I am getting this error.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] 'D:\16032022\Dwarkesh\dwarkesh_estate_android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1166334359.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #190): leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

screenshot of my AndroidManifest file, which shows 0 errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated LeakCanary Version

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.12'
```